# Evaluate "Shell command line with shell variables" from python OR evaluate python string as shell command line

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables, pass-by-reference, slurm

CONTEXT

I am working on a simulation cluster.
In order to make as flexible as possible (working with different simulation soft) , we created a python file that parse a config file defining environment variables, and command line to start the simulation. This command is launched through SLURM sbatch command (shell $COMMAND)

ISSUE

From python, all Environment variables are enrolled reading the config file
I have issue with variable COMMAND that is using other environment variables (displayed as shell variable)

For example

```
COMMAND = "fluent -3ddp -n$NUMPROCS -hosts=./hosts -file $JOBFILE"    
os.environ['COMMAND']=COMMAND    
NUMPROCS = "32"    
os.environ['NUMPROCS']=NUMPROCS    
[...]    
exe = Popen(['sbatch','template_document.sbatch'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

sbatch distribute COMMAND to all simulation nodes as COMMAND being a command line

COMMAND recalls other saved env. variables. Shell interprets it strictly as text... Which makes the command line fails. it is strictly as a string using $ not variable for example :
`'fluent -3ddp -n$NUMPROCS -hosts=./hosts -file $JOBFILE'`

SOLUTION I AM LOOKING FOR

I am looking for a simple solution
Solution 1: A 1 to 3 python command lines to evaluate the COMMAND as shell command to echo
Solution 2: A Shell command to evaluate the variables within the "string" $COMMAND as a variable
At the end the command launched from within sbatch should be

```
fluent -3ddp -n32 -hosts=./hosts -file /path/to/JOBFILE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Partial or no support for bash's variable substitution, e.g. implement some python functionality to reproduces bash's `$VARIABLE` syntax.
2. Reproduce all of bash's variable substitution facilities which are supported in the config file (`$VARIABLE`, `${VARIABLE}`, `${VARIABLE/x/y}`, `$(cmd)` - whatever.
3. Let bash do the heavy lifting, for the cost of performance and possibly security, depending on your trust of the content of the config files.

I'll show the third one here, since it's the most resilient (again, security issues notwithstanding). Let's say you have this config file, `config.py`:

```
REGULAR   =   "some-text"
EQUALS = "hello = goodbye" # trap #1: search of '='
SUBST = "decorated $REGULAR"
FANCY   = "xoxo${REGULAR}xoxo"
CMDOUT = "$(date)"
BASH_A = "trap" # trap #2: avoid matching variables like BASH_ARGV
QUOTES = "'\"" # trap #3: quoting
```

Then your python program can run the following incantation:

```
bash -c 'source <(sed "s/^/export /" config.py | sed "s/[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*/=/") && env | grep -f <(cut -d= -f1 config.py | grep -E -o "\w+" | sed "s/.*/^&=/")'
```

which will produce the following output:

```
SUBST=decorated some-text
CMDOUT=Thu Nov 28 12:18:50 PST 2019
REGULAR=some-text
QUOTES='"
FANCY=xoxosome-textxoxo
EQUALS=hello = goodbye
BASH_A=trap
```

Which you can then read with python, but note that the quotes are now gone, so you'll have to account for that.

**Explanation of the incantation:**

`bash -c 'source ...instructions... && env | grep ...expressions...'` tells bash to read & interpret the instructions, then grep the environment for the expressions. We're going to turn the config file into instructions which modify bash's environment.

If you try using `set` instead of `env`, the output will be inconsistent with respect to quoting. Using `env` avoids trap #3.

**Instructions**: We're going to create instructions for the form:

```
export FANCY="xoxo${REGULAR}xoxo"
```

so that bash can interpret them and `env` can read them.

- `sed "s/^/export /" config.py` prefixes the variables with `export`.
- `sed "s/[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*/=/"` converts the assignment format to syntax that bash can read with `source`. Using `s/x/y/` instead of `s/x/y/g` avoids trap #1.
- `source <(...command...)` causes bash to treat the output of the command as a file and run its lines, one by one.

Of course, one way to avoid this complexity is to have the file use bash syntax to begin with. If that were the case, we would use `source config.sh` instead of `source <(...command...)`.

**Expressions**: We want to grep the output of `env` for patterns like `^FANCY=`.

- `cut -d= -f1 config.py | grep -E -o "\w+"` finds the variable names in `config.py`.
- `sed "s/.*/^&=/"` turns variable names like `FANCY` to grep search expressions such as `^FANCY=`. This is to avoid trap #2.
- `grep -f <(...command...)` gets `grep` to treat the output of the command as a file containing one search expression in each line, which in this case would be `^FANCY=`, `^CMDOUT=` etc.

**EDIT**

Since you actually want to just pass this environment to another bash command rather than use it in python, you can actually just have python run this:

```
bash -c 'source <(sed "s/^/export /" config.py | sed "s/[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*/=/") && $COMMAND'
```

(assuming that `COMMAND` is specified in the config file).

Comment: Hello @Root
Thanks a lot for your so detailed and quick answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot : that is exactly my need - will test and let you know

Answer (score 0):

It seems I have not explained well enough the issue, but your 3rd solution seems replying to my expectations... though so far I did not manage to adapt it

Based on your 3rd solution BASH, I will make it more straight :
Let's say I have got following after running python, and this that cannot be modified

```
EXPORT COMMAND='fluent -3ddp -n$NUMPROCS -hosts=./hosts -file $JOBFILE'
EXPORT JOBFILE='/path/to/jobfile'
EXPORT NUMPROCS='32'
EXPORT WHATSOEVER='SPECIFIC VARIABLE TO SIMULATION SOFTWARE'
```

I wish to execute the following from the slurm batch file (bash), using $COMMAND / $JOBFILE /$NUMPROCS

```
fluent -3ddp -n32-hosts=./hosts -file /path/to/jobfile
```

Please note : I have backup solution in python  -  I managed to substitute $VARIABLE by its value - based on the assumption $VARIABLE is not composed by another $variable... using regex substitution... just it looks so many lines to have what seemed to me simple request